# How to include Hover in my @extend as a shared style?

Tags: css, sass, frontend, extend

Like the title says, how do I go about adding hover to my @extended styles?

I will add a link to my Codepen here: https://codepen.io/UserBrayann/pen/gOvmzwN

SCSS

```
  %box-shared {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use the hover in the scss while also using @extend.

```
%box-shared {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 19px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  
  &:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```